# how to loop through scale_fill_cyclical and assign legend labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I wanted to mimic and loop through the structure in the Catalan election example in the link below, how should I assign the legend label within scale_fill_cyclical()?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggjoy/vignettes/gallery.html

Instead of years for rows in the example, I have months, and 12 scenarios to compare against a historical record, so I'm looking for 12 of these plots. For comparison purpose, it's as if I'm keeping Indy for each plot (Indy would be my historical scenario), and using Unionist as a slot for a for loop of individual scenarios.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)
Catalan_elections %>%
mutate(YearFct = fct_rev(as.factor(Year))) %>%
ggplot(aes(y = YearFct)) +
geom_joy(aes(x = Percent, fill = paste(YearFct, Option)), 
         alpha = .8, color = "white", from = 0, to = 100) +
labs(x = "Vote (%)",
     y = "Election Year",
   title = "Indy vs Unionist vote in Catalan elections",
   subtitle = "Analysis unit: municipalities (n = 949)",
   caption = "Marc Belzunces (@marcbeldata) | Source: Idescat") +
scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
scale_fill_cyclical(breaks = c("1980 Indy", "1980 Unionist"),
                  labels = c(`1980 Indy` = "Indy", `1980 Unionist` = "Unionist"),
                  values = c("#ff0000", "#0000ff", "#ff8080", "#8080ff"),
                  name = "Option", guide = "legend") +
theme_joy(grid = FALSE)
```

The 12 plots are drawing nicely with cyclical fill just as I hoped, it's just that the legend text for the comparison scenario, or "Unionist", (the text for the blue) is showing the month and the scenario. Just like 1980 was arbitrarily picked as one of the years for the legend, I chose September arbitrarily for mine, but don't want it in the legend. My suspicion is that quote formatting isn't right, and  `paste1` is the problem in the label call. It seems to be reading the breaks correctly, as it's scaling cyclically correctly.

```
 scenarios <- c("hist", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "cwc30", "l1", "l2", "l3", "l4", "l5", "cwc70")
 paste1 <- paste0("Sept"," ",scenarios[i])
```

factor setting and ggplot and geom calls as above, then:

```
 scale_fill_cyclical(breaks= c("Sept hist", paste1),                 
              labels = c(`Sept hist` = "Historical (Q0)",  `paste1` = paste(scenarios[i])),                  
              values = c("#ff0000", "#0000ff", "#ff8080", "#8080ff"),
              name = "scenario", guide = "legend")
```

In a nutshell, I just want the scenario "e2" in the legend, not "Sept e2".

[image]

Comment: Can you post the reproducible code block for your problem? I guess the `paste1` is indeed the issue. I tried changing it to a character value and this changes to a correct legend value even when the month is added in the paste function.